# xdotool prints 8 instead of Tab

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, xdotool

I'm currently working on a "autotype"-script for [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/).
In oder to do that, I need to type the username, press 'Tab' and then type the password.

For testing I'm using the following code:

```
WID=$(xdotool selectwindow)
xdotool windowactivate $WID type --delay 100 "Hello World"
xdotool windowactivate $WID key --clearmodifiers Tab
xdotool windowactivate $WID type --delay 100 "Hello World"
```

Then I select `kate` as window, but the output is `Hello World8Hello World` instead of `Hello World    Hello World`.
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
As workaround you can use `xte 'key Tab'` from the `xautomation` package. But the original question still remains.

Comment: Have you tried with something like "\\010" (adjust amount of backslashes as needed) instead of "Tab"? Or maybe the key code of your Tab key?

Comment: No, but 'Tab' is a keyword, because 'tab' throws an error

Comment: You should simplify your commands by using `windowactivate` only once, and remove the `--delay` options, and then add `--sync` to the `windowactivate` to make xdotool wait until it is done.

Comment: I do not have `xdotool` and cannot therefore experiment with it. However, if you change the communication with it then the problem might go away.

Comment: This doesn't work as well: `xdotool windowactivate --sync $WID;
    xdotool type  "Hello World";
    xdotool key --clearmodifiers  Tab;
    xdotool type  "Hello World";`

Comment: And `\\010` gives you `Error: Invalid key sequence '\010'.
Failure converting key sequence '\010' to keycodes`

Answer (score 1):

`xdotool` is looking for an *"X Keysym"* string, but its documentation in regard to how it determines this is terse:

> Generally, any valid X Keysym string will work. Multiple keys are
>              separated by '+'. Aliases exist for "alt", "ctrl", "shift",
>              "super", and "meta" which all map to Foo_L, such as **`Alt_L`** and
>              **`Control_L`**, etc.

I used keycodes such as `0xff09` (the keycode for **Tab**) when developing a page on xterm's [special keys](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/modified-keys.html).  With that approach, I was able to send all of the keys which were defined in my keyboard configuration.

My command-line differed.  Just the relevant part of a test-script shows this:

```
KEY=0xff09      # XK_tab

sendkey() {                                                                     
        echo "** $1"                                                            
        xdotool key --window $ID $1 2>/dev/null                                 
}

sendkey "$KEY"
```

Your problematic command would be

```
xdotool windowactivate $ID key --clearmodifiers $1 2>/dev/null
```

`xdotool`'s manual suggests that it may be necessary to add a `--sync` option, and implies that command-chaining will work (so that `windowactivate` and `key` chain together), but that combination does not work for me, either.  But the `--window` option of `key` does work:

```
xdotool key --window $ID --clearmodifiers $1 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a bit old but maybe this will help someone..
you can use KP_Tab or KP_Enter as well for example

Comment: Does that address the question?

Comment: It won’t help anybody if you don’t explain how it answers the question.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your post to make it clearer and more complete.